# Show balance by month - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data about bank transactions. For example, I have two attributes "Posting date" and "Value". I want to see bank balance by each month. Problem is, that if I create measure and then add to graph (by months) I get SUM by each month in graph, but this is not balance.

For example, if data:

- 01.01.2019 (500€)
- 02.01.2019 (100€)
- 24.01.2019 (-50€)
- 25.01.2019 (-200€)
- 04.02.2019 (100€)
- 15.02.2019 (-50€)
- 03.03.2019 (200€)

I need that kind of result:

- January (350€)
- February (400€)
- March (600€)

But I get:

- January (350€)
- February (50€)
- March (200€)

Comment: You need to define more precisely what "balance" means. Is it a cumulative sum from the beginning of data? or a cumulative sum from the start of the year? or rolling amount over some period of time?

Comment: @RADO i mean cumulative sum from beginning of data.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table in your data model?

Comment: @RADO, no I don't have calendar table, I have only "Posting date" (Datetime) value in dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
Balance = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Dataset[Value] ); 
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Dataset);
        Dataset[Posting Date] <= MAX (Dataset[Posting Date] )
    )
)
```